# Is the benefit of the IO monad pattern for handling side effects purely academic?

Tags: python, functional-programming, state, side-effect, monad

*Sorry for yet another FP + side effects question, but I couldn't find an existing one which quite answered this for me.*

My (limited) understanding of functional programming is that state/side effects should be minimised and kept separate from stateless logic.

I also gather Haskell’s approach to this, the IO monad, achieves this by wrapping stateful actions in a container, for later execution, considered outside the scope of the program itself.

I’m trying to understand this pattern, but actually to determine whether to use it in a Python project, so want to avoid Haskell specifics if poss.

Crude example incoming.

If my program converts an XML file to a JSON file:

```
def main():
    xml_data = read_file('input.xml')  # impure
    json_data = convert(xml_data)  # pure
    write_file('output.json', json_data) # impure
```

Isn’t the IO monad’s approach effectively to do this:

```
steps = list(
    read_file,
    convert,
    write_file,
)
```

then absolve itself of responsibility by not actually *calling* those steps, but letting the interpreter do it?

Or put another way, it’s like writing:

```
def main():  # pure
    def inner():  # impure
        xml_data = read_file('input.xml')
        json_data = convert(xml_data)
        write_file('output.json', json_data)
    return inner
```

then expecting someone else to call `inner()` and saying your job is done because `main()` is pure.

The whole program is going to end up contained in the IO monad, basically.

When the code is actually *executed*, everything after reading the file depends on that file’s state so will still suffer from the same state-related bugs as the imperative implementation, so have you actually gained anything, as a programmer who will maintain this?

I totally appreciate the benefit of *reducing* and *isolating* stateful behaviour, which is in fact why I structured the imperative version like that: gather inputs, do pure stuff, spit out outputs. Hopefully `convert()` can be completely pure and reap the benefits of cachability, threadsafety, etc.

I also appreciate that monadic types can be useful, especially in pipelines operating on comparable types, but don’t see why IO should use monads unless already in such a pipeline.

Is there some additional benefit to dealing with side effects the IO monad pattern brings, which I’m missing?

Comment: **You should watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkZFtimgAcM).**  *The wonders of monads are finally revealed without resorting to Category Theory or Haskell. It turns out that monads are trivially expressed in JavaScript, and are one of the key enablers of Ajax. Monads are amazing. They are simple things, almost trivially implemented, with enormous power to manage complexity. But understanding them is surprisingly difficult, and most people, once they have that ah-ha moment, seem to lose the ability to explain them to others.*

Comment: Good video, thanks. I actually learnt about this stuff from a JS intro to functional programming (then read a million more…). Although having watched that, I'm fairly sure my question is specific to the IO monad, which Crock doesn't cover in that video.

Comment: Hmm... Isn't AJAX considered a form of I/O?

Comment: Note that the type of `main` in a Haskell program is `IO ()` — an IO action.  This isn't actually a function at all; it's a *value*.  Your whole program is a pure value containing instructions that tell the language runtime what it should do.  All the impure stuff (actually performing the IO actions) is outside the scope of your program.

Comment: In your example, the monadic part is when you to take the result of one computation (`read_file`) and use it as an argument to the next one (`write_file`). If you only had a sequence of independent actions, you wouldn't need a Monad.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is because “understanding” something has a very vague meaning. Many people can learn a new concept, use the concept to solve problems, use variations on it to solve more problems, generalise it, recognise this in surprising situations – yet they might still have the feeling “they don't get it”. But if they can do all this, they probably understood a part of it.

Comment: @lortabac not true, e.g. function that simply prints "hello" then prints "bye" still needs the (IO) monad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The whole program is going to end up contained in the IO monad, basically.

That's the bit where I think you're not seeing it from the Haskellers' perspective.  So we have a program like this:

```
module Main

main :: IO ()
main = do
  xmlData <- readFile "input.xml"
  let jsonData = convert xmlData
  writeFile "output.json" jsonData

convert :: String -> String
convert xml = ...
```

I think a typical Haskeller's take on this would be that `convert`, the pure part:

1. Is probably the bulk of this program, and by far more complicated than the `IO` parts;
2. Can be reasoned about and tested without having to deal with `IO` at all.

So they don't see this as `convert` being "contained" in `IO`, but rather, as it being **isolated** from `IO`.  From its type, whatever `convert` does can never depend on anything that happens in an `IO` action.

> When the code is actually executed, everything after reading the file depends on that file’s state so will still suffer from the same state-related bugs as the imperative implementation, so have you actually gained anything, as a programmer who will maintain this?

I'd say that this splits into two things:

1. When the program runs, the value of the *argument* to `convert` depends on the state of the file.
2. But what the `convert` function *does*, that doesn't depend on the state of the file.  `convert` is always **the same function**, even if it is invoked with different arguments at different points.

This is a somewhat abstract point, but it's really key to what Haskellers mean when they talk about this.  You want to write `convert` in such a way that given **any** valid argument, it will produce a correct result for that argument.  When you look at it like that, the fact that reading a file is a stateful operation doesn't enter into the equation; all that matters is that whatever argument is fed to it and wherever that may have come from, `convert` must handle it correctly.  And the fact that purity restricts what `convert` can do with its input simplifies that reasoning.

So if `convert` produces incorrect results from some arguments, and `readFile` feeds it such an argument, we don't see that as a bug introduced by *state*.  It's a bug in a pure function!

Comment: I think this is the best description (although the others helped clarify things for me too), thanks.

Comment: is it worth noting that using monads in python may have less benefit as python only has one (static) type, and therefore wont make any guarantees about anything?

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to be sure exactly what you mean by "purely academic", but I think the answer is mostly "no".

As explained in [Tackling the Awkward Squad](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/) by Simon Peyton Jones (**strongly** recommended reading!), monadic I/O was meant to solve real problems with the way Haskell used to handle I/O. Read the example of the server with Requests and Responses, which I won't copy here; it's very instructive.

Haskell, unlike Python, encourages a style of "pure" computation which can be enforced by its type system. Of course, you can use self-discipline when programming in Python to comply with this style, but what about modules you didn't write? Without much help from the type system (and common libraries), monadic I/O is probably less useful in Python. The philosophy of the language is just not meant to enforce a strict pure/impure separation.

Note that this says more about the different philosophies of Haskell and Python than about how academic monadic I/O is. I wouldn't use it for Python.

One other thing. You say:

> The whole program is going to end up contained in the IO monad, basically.

It's true the Haskell `main` function "lives" in `IO`, but real Haskell programs are encouraged not to use `IO` whenever it isn't needed. Almost every function you write that doesn't need to do I/O shouldn't have type `IO`.

So I'd say in your last example you got it backwards: `main` is impure (because it reads and writes files) but core functions like `convert` are pure.

Answer (score 5):

*Why* is IO impure?  Because it may return different values at different times.  There is a dependency on time that *must* be accounted for, one way or another.  This is even more crucial with lazy evaluation.  Consider the following program:

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "Please enter your name"  
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ name
```

Without an IO monad, why would the first prompt ever get output?  There is nothing depending on it, so lazy evaluation means it will never get demanded.   There is also nothing compelling the prompt to be output before the input is read.  As far as the computer is concerned, without an IO monad, those first two expressions are completely independent of each other.  Fortunately, `name` imposes an order on the second two.

There are other ways to solve the problem of order dependency, but using an IO monad is probably the simplest way (from the language point of view at least) to allow everything to stay in the lazy functional realm, without little sections of imperative code.  It's also the most flexible.  For example, you can relatively easily build an IO pipeline dynamically at runtime based on user input.

Answer (score 4):

> My (limited) understanding of functional programming is that state/side effects
> should be minimised and kept separate from stateless logic.

That's not just functional programming; that's usually a good idea in any language. If you do unit testing, the way you split apart `x = read_file()`, `y = convert(x)` and `write_file(y)` comes perfectly naturally because, despite `convert()` being by far the most complex and largest part of the code, writing tests for it is relatively easy: all you need to set up is the input parameter. Writing tests for `read_file()` and `write_file()` is quite a bit harder (even though the functions themselves are almost trivial) because you need to create and/or read things on the file system before and after calling the function. Ideally you'd make such functions so simple that you feel comfortable not testing them and thus save yourself a lot of hassle.

The difference between Python and Haskell here is that Haskell has a type checker that can prove that functions have no side effects. In Python you need to hope that nobody's accidentally dropped in a file-reading or -writing function into `convert()` (say, `read_config_file()`). In Haskell when you declare `convert :: String -> String` or similar, with no `IO` monad, the type checker will guarantee that this is a pure function that relies only on its input parameter and nothing else. If someone tries to modify `convert` to read a config file they will quickly see compiler errors showing that they'd be breaking the purity of the function. (And hopefully they'd be sensible enough to move `read_config_file` out of `convert` and pass its result into `convert`, maintaining the purity.)

Answer (score 2):

Monads have benefits for isolating IO in *Haskell*, but this benefit cannot be transferred to Python because of fundamental differences in the languages.

The primary difference is that Haskell is designed to *only* allow IO operations through the IO monad. If a function does not have `IO` in the signature, you can be sure it will *never* have any side-effects. Purity is guaranteed by the type system.

But in Python, any arbitrary function can perform IO and have side effects. Introducing monads for some functions does not change that. So there is no way to get that isolation anyway.

A second reason monads are necessary in Haskell is because of its lazy nature. Consider this code:

```
 print("Hello")
 print("World")
```

In Python these statements are automatically executed in linear order. But Haskell is lazy and only execute functions when the return value is used by some other function. But if a function only has side effects and doesn't return a result, it would never be executed! Monads are a mechanism which chains operations and force them to be executed in a linear order - something which is not necessary in Python in the first place.

Finally I will point out the Python code example is *not* a monad. It just an example of returning a function as a value. Monads are a specific pattern for function chaining, where functions are chained together with a bind function, invoking each function in the chain. Just wrapping a function in another function does not make it a monad - it just introduces an unnecessary indirection.

All that said, I do think it has a benefit in Python to isolate IO in certain functions rather than having IO happen everywhere the program. I believe this pattern is called **Functional Core Imperative Shell**.